# How does this regular expression use it's capturing groups to replace single quote with double quotes

Tags: javascript, nsregularexpression

let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";

Console.log(text.replace(/(^|\W)'|'(\W|$)/g, '$1"$2'));

This code was meant to convert single quotes in sentences into double quotes without affecting single quotes used in contractions like *aren't*

I understand the or statements and everything, even the pipe character. I just don't understand how the capturing and replacement is done for each single quote. For every single quote that is replaced, what is the value of $1 and $2. Am confused?

I understand the regular expression used. I just don't understand fully how it executes in this particular scenario.

At first it checks for if any beginning of line(^) proceeds a single quote. It finds one in the first word ('I'm). So let's say the first capture is the ^ indicating beginning of a line. So $1 is an empty space. Now I dnt get how it gets $2. Because I know it has to get $2 so it can place double quotes in between them to get $1"$2.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you said  you understood the expression, but just for clarity `/(^|\W)'|'(\W|$)/` is an alternation between two (outer) alternatives: `(^|\W)'` and `'(\W|$)`. Each match will match one or the other of those subexpressions (which are also alternations, but that's not important here). Since the alternatives have capture groups in them, that means that one of the groups will have something in it, and the other won't, since only one alternative can match. When you give the `replace` method a replacement string with placeholders like `$1` and `$2`, it'll use a blank string for a capture group that has no value.

To see exactly what the groups end up containing, you can pass a replacement *function* to `replace` instead of a replacement *string*. The function will receive the complete match as its first argument, the first capture group as its second argument, the second capture group as its third argument, etc.; the replacement is whatever the function returns. So if you swap the replacment string for a replacement function, you can use the debugger to look at the values of (in the below) `c1` and `c2` (or log them out as I have in the snippet below). Unlike when you give `replace` a replacement string, though, when you give it a function it'll give you the value `undefined` (not a blank string) for a capture group that has no value, so we'll need to handle that in our function.

Here's an example of doing that:

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
console.log(text.replace(/(^|\W)'|'(\W|$)/g, (match, c1, c2) => {
    // Build result, replacing `undefined` with `""`
    const result = `${c1 ?? ""}"${c2 ?? ""}`;
    // Show what was received and what result was produced
    console.log({match, c1, c2, result});
    // Return the result
    return result;
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: You said this: When you give the replace method a replacement string with placeholders like $1 and $2, it'll use a blank string for a capture group that has no value. My question is, if you use replace method on a simple regex, and it finds only one match instead of both $1 and $2, the entire operation will just fail. But why does it succeed in the case you explained above? Why does the engine replace the capture group that has no value with an empty string? Why doesn't it just fail? Is it because we are dealing with OR gate in my original question?

Comment: @JamilSamir - It works because your overall pattern is an alternation between two subexpressions, so that pattern matches when *either* alternative is a match. For instance, the `'` at the very beginning matches `(^|\W)'`, your first subexpression, so its capture group is `""` (representing the beginning of input). Since the first alternative matched, the second alternative, `'(\W|$)`, isn't used, and its capture group has no value. If the second alternative had matched instead (it never does in the sample sentence), the first alternative's capture group would have no value.

Comment: I understand what you said about the  other alternative not needing to match if the the other one matches. But am just confused about the replacement expression, $1"$2. Since " has to be enclosed between $1 and $2, and $2 doesn't exist, meaning we just have $1, the final solution for the first match of text will be $1"_ . The underscore is d position for would have been $2 if it existed. So that's just the confusing part for me. I thought if you had $1"$2. You need to have both $1 and $2 values so that the engine can pinpoint exactly where " will be placed.

Comment: @JamilSamir - That's what I mean about `replace` using `""` as the value of the placeholder when you pass in a replacement string. Since the second capture group doesn't have any value, `replace` defaults to using a blank string for it. Let's use the second match as an example: The match is `,'`, the first capture group is `,` so `$1` is `,`, and the second capture group has no value, so `replace` uses a blank string for `$2`. So `$1"$2` is `,` plus `"` plus a blank string: `,"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$1` and `$2` will always exist for that expression, and will be treated as a zero-length string for uncaptured values.  Let's look at the results of a slightly modified version using a sentence that uses both capture groups.

```
let text="'Eet's insensitif of you to call me a 'Grammar Nazi'!'";
console.log(text.replace(/(^|\W)'|'(\W|$)/g, '[$$1=$1,$$2=$2]'));
```

It replaces all the relevant matches with info contained in square brackets, which happens in four different places.

```
[$1=,$2=]Eet's insensitif of you to call me a[$1= ,$2=]Grammar Nazi[$1=,$2=!][$1=,$2=]

[$1=,$2=]  In match 1, line start was matched in $1 and $2 had no match.
[$1= ,$2=] In match 2, a space was matched in $1 and $2 had no match.
[$1=,$2=!] In match 3, $1 had no match and $2 matched the exclamation mark.
[$1=,$2=]  In match 4, $1 had no match and $2 matched the line end.
```

When both matches are taken together, you'll always end up with one captured match and one empty match.  So, the sequence `$1"$2` will always fill in both `$1` and `$2` with a quotation mark between them but it's guaranteed that one of those two captures will be empty.

```
console.log(text.replace(/(^|\W)'|'(\W|$)/g, '$1"$2'));

"Eet's insensitif of you to call me a "Grammar Nazi"!"
```